Hooking into ConTeXt's shipout routine
I read somewhere on this stack that
\installshipoutmethod{myshipoutmethod}{
    \commandOne
    \commandTwo
     ...
    \commandN
    \invokepagehandler{normal}
}

\setuppaper[method=myshipoutmethod]

allows one to hook into ConTeXt's output routine.
I've been playing around with it, hoping that I could use it to see when a section title has been placed in the MVL so that I can record which page it occured on.
Here's my somewhat patchy solution.

Fire off an \addtoqueue command to store the title name in a queue
Inspect the queue during the ORT and write the
names and pages in the queue to a log file
Process the log file during a second run

The main problem I run into with the solution has to do with ConTeXt's asyncoronous ORT. I'm finding that sometimes sections that straddle page boundaries fire off the \addtoqueue method too early, causing their contents to be added to the log file before they've been appended to the MVL. It's rare, but when it happens it is a nuisance.
I was wondering if there's a way to check if a title (or anything for that matter) has been added to the MVL -- as opposed to what my solution does which is check to see if something has been processed by ConTeXt before the ORT is invoked -- using the hook mentioned above?
Another problem I ran into, but managed to find a hack around, is ConTeXt's tendency to erase anything done during the ORT. I'm finding that if I do something like
\newcount\mycount \mycount=1

\installshipoutmethod{myshipoutmethod}{
    \advance\mycount by 1
    ...
} 

ConTeXt will reset the register once it exits the ORT. It will also not allow me to create new macros or change old ones -- well it does but only for the duration of the ORT.
Like I said, I managed to find a workaround using Lua, but I'm still curious, can I get the output routine to persist any changes I made while it was running?
Thanks in advance! Appreciate the help!

Messing with the OR is generally a bad idea, so it's best to avoid that if possible. TeX expands the output routine in a group, so you need to write \global\advance[…] and \global\def[…] or \aftergrouped{\advance[…] \def[…] to change the values globally.

That makes sense.
I wouldn’t say I’m messing with the OR. There just seems to be no other way of accomplishing what I need.
Is there another way to determine when ConTeXt has added something to the MVL and to log what was added to a file?

I'm not sure what your goal is here, but I don't think that hooking into the output routine is the best way to do this. Instead, you could either define a command that prints its page number, or you can use the built-in section page referencing mechanism to do that for you.
%% Just for the demonstration, to show multiple pages at once
\setuppapersize[A7, landscape][A5, landscape]
\setuppaper[nx=2,ny=2]
\setuparranging[XY]
\showframe[edge][edge]
\definecolor[layout:page][s=0]

\startsetups[*default]
    \directsetup{*reset}
    \clubpenalty=0
    \widowpenalty=0
\stopsetups

%% Demonstration
\starttext
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    %%% OPTION 1 %%%
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

    %% Define a command to get the page number at the current position
    \newcount\pagenumberherecount
    \define\pagenumberhere{%
        \global\advance\pagenumberherecount by 1
        \pagereference[pagenumberhere:\the\pagenumberherecount]%
        \ref[page][pagenumberhere:\the\pagenumberherecount]%
    }

    %% Demonstration
    \dorecurse{8}{%
        \section{This is on page~\pagenumberhere}
    }

    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    %%% OPTION 2 %%%
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

    %% Manually set the reference name using the ``reference'' key, then use the %% ``at'' command to refer to it

    %% Demonstration
    \section[title={This is on \at{page}[section:1]}, reference={section:1}]

    \subsection[title={This is on \at{page}[section:2]}, reference={section:2}]

    \subsection[title={This is on \at{page}[section:3]}, reference={section:3}]

    \subsubsection[title={Another section}, reference={anything-goes-here}]

    This section started on \at{page}[anything-goes-here], and we are currently
    on \pagereference[page:location-a]\at{page}[page:location-a]. Even though we
    are now on the next page, we can still see that this section started on
    \at{page}[anything-goes-here].
\stoptext



Yup, that works really well! Appreciate the help!
